# Is it strange to say "be geek"?

Tags: grammar

I know the word "geek" is noun and adjective form is "geeky", so it is grammatically incorrect to say "be geek". But putting grammar aside, does "be geek" still sound strange?

**More background and context**

I want to say "be geek, be kind" in the subtile of my blog, but I wonder I should say "be geeky, be kind", instead.

Comment: Just opinion, but it sounds strange to me...

Comment: "There is no great beauty that hath not some strangeness in the proportion." -- Sir Francis Bacon

Answer (score 4):

*Geek* and *geeky* have a wide variety of meanings. Until about six or eight years ago the sense was usually negative; but the geeks themselves started wearing the label with pride, and the meaning has shifted,

I think it quite proper to invent a new way of using the word to express a distinctive meaning. This particular use, *be geek* suggests that you are inviting the reader not to be ***a** geek*, a social role to which certain qualities are attributed; certainly not *be geek**y***, to exhibit certain (usually deprecated) behaviors; but to aspire to the noble qualities of geekitude, to release their inner geek.

In any case, it's your blog, and you can say anything you like.

Comment: > but geeky is almost always negative.

Comment: I never know _geeky_ is used with negative meaning. Yes, you got my intention completely right. This somewhat assures me that _be geek_ works even if it is not grammatically correct.

Comment: @kimh I really like it!

Comment: There's a subculture in which *geeky* is used positively.  See for example this article titled [*10 Ultra Creative and Geeky Bento Box Lunches*](http://www.techeblog.com/index.php/tech-gadget/10-ultra-creative-and-geeky-bento-box-lunches), where I don't think the word has a negative connotation.

Comment: @snailplane I was not aware of that, though I knew that *geek* itself is now positive as often as not. I'll fix.